# Auto-generated pretty permalink not using title since 4.4 update

Tags: permalinks, updates

I have pretty permalinks enabled. Now when I save a draft and/or publish a post, half the time it just uses the post ID as the permalink instead of the title. This started happening after the 4.4 updated.

Any ideas for how to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is standard behavior for drafts. I've used pretty permalinks on every page I've built, and drafts are always directed to the "ugly" URL. If you publish the post, the actual permalink will be set as expected.

Side note: When you edit the draft, you should see the actual permalink listed at the top of the page (small print, just above the title). Even clicking on that will direct you to the "ugly" link.

I suspect it's tied to the fact that you are viewing a post *preview* specifically.

Comment: The peramlink remains the same when it's published too. I've been using Wordpress for 7 years and I'm certain the pretty permalink is generated as soon as you enter the title and it auto-saves the draft.

Comment: The permalink is "generated", yes, but it's not "active". While a post is in draft form, the saved permalink returns a 404. (I've got pre 4.4 installs currently doing the same thing). I tested this before answering on, and it behaved exactly as I described. It's possible you have some plugin component defined somewhere that overrides how permalinks work with drafts, and if that's the case, 4.4 may have broken that plugin causing this issue.

Comment: -- Additionally, the same will happen if you preview changes to an existing post. You'll get an "ugly" permalink, and not the "pretty one" -- Running low on space in last comment, sorry.